# facebook hashtag count using graph API v2.1 in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

I want to get the total count for hashtag of facebook using Graph API v2.1, But every time i get error

i used this query for hashtag_count in Graph API

/v2.1/hashtag_counts?hashtags[]=pepsi&since=1400716800&access_token={app_id}|{app_seccret}

```
{
    "error": 
    {
        "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "code": 3
    }
}
```

How to apply in Public Content Solution program...?

Comment: So the first thing you read on the documentation for that API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/hashtag_counter/v2.1) is "This API is restricted to partners in the Public Content Solutions program. Learn more about the program and how you can apply here".

Comment: How to apply in Public Content Solution program...?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's written in the first sentence of the according documentation athttps://developers.facebook.com/docs/hashtag_counter/v2.1

> This API is restricted to partners in the Public Content Solutions program

I guess your app is not whitelisted.

Comment: is there any other way to do it...?